# Capture the form inputs in the console

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

How do I capture the values of the form in the console. currently am getting an empty object in the console.

```
<div class="cont">
      <v-form
            ref="form"
            class="form sign-in"
            v-model="valid"
           lazy-validation
                        >
                      
    <v-text-field
      v-model="email"
         :rules="emailRules"
         label="E-mail"
         outlined
       required></v-text-field>
      <v-text-field v-model="password"
        :counter="10"
         label="Password"
         required
        append-icon="mdi-map-marker"
        ></v-text-field>
        <v-btn
         :disabled="!valid"
         color="success"
          class="submit mr-8"
       @click="submit" >Submit
           </v-btn>
   </v-form>
            </div>
        </template>
        
 

     <script>
          export default {
            data: () => ({
              form:{
                name: '',
                email: '',
                password: ''
              },
              valid: true,
              email: '',
              emailRules: [
                v => !!v || 'E-mail is required',
                v => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || 'E-mail must be valid',
              ],
            }),
        
            methods: {
              submit () {
                console.log(this.form)
              },
            },
          }
        </script>
```

I want to see the data of the form when you click the submit button

I want to get the form details name email and password.

what i get now is

```
{__ob__: Observer}email: ""name: ""password: ""__ob__: Observerdep: Dep {_pending: false, id: 246, subs: Array(0)}mock: falseshallow: falsevalue: {__ob__: Observer}vmCount: 0[[Prototype]]: Objectget email: ƒ reactiveGetter()length: 0name: "reactiveGetter"prototype: {constructor: ƒ}arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
```

Comment: Had to remove one textfield to shorten code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind the `form` property fields to the inputs like `v-model="form.name"` and `v-model="form.email"` ..., and remove the other properties `name`,`email` and `password`  :

```html
   <v-text-field
              v-model="form.email"
              :rules="emailRules"
              label="E-mail"
              outlined
              required
            ></v-text-field>
```